# MySQL left join query with conditions - timing out

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, left-join

I have 2 table types, 1) properties 2) booked dates.

The query below should be selecting the properties which don't have the relevant booked dates in the availability table.

```
SELECT prop.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(50.2375800) ) * cos( radians(prop.latitude) ) * cos( radians(prop.longitude ) - radians(-3.7697910) ) + sin( radians(50.2375800) ) * sin( radians(prop.latitude)))) AS dstnc 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `props_01` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `props_03`) AS prop 
LEFT JOIN `availability` AS avail ON prop.unique_code=avail.ucode AND (avail.date != '20131228' AND avail.date != '20131229' AND avail.date != '20131230') 
WHERE `status`='on' AND avail.ucode IS NULL AND prop.country!='Wales' 
GROUP BY `unique_code` 
HAVING dstnc <= 2 
ORDER BY prop.sleeps ASC, prop.package ASC
```

The `props_XX` tables contain the property data, whilst the `availability` table contains 3 columns (a unique id / property code "ucode" / booked dates "date"), these tables reference each property with a unique 10 character code.

Even when I only execute the query with just one property table it still timesout

When I don't include the availability part of the query it runs fine, however with the availability dates the query seems to be stuck in a loop and ultimately timesout.

Can someone please help with a solution, thanks.

Comment: What indexes are on the properties tables?

Comment: First of all, dont use wildcard `prop.*`. Further more, search your bottleneck by removing peace by peace. Start with the cosinux calculation by moving it to PHP.

Comment: On the property tables the indexes are that `unique_code` is infact unique. Each property table has between 400 and 4000 records, while the booked dates table has around 500k of records

Comment: @JaMaBing - the 'prop' table has around 20 columns, all of which are to be used when displaying the results

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide information on the sizes of the tables or the size of the resulting result set.  I assume, from the name, that `prop.unique_code` is actually unique.

Here is the query formatted so I can read it better:

```
SELECT prop.*, . . . 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `props_01` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `props_03`
     ) AS prop LEFT JOIN
     `availability` AS avail
     ON prop.unique_code = avail.ucode AND
        (avail.date not in ('20131228', '20131229', '20131230') 
WHERE `status` = 'on' AND avail.ucode IS NULL AND prop.country != 'Wales' 
GROUP BY `unique_code` 
HAVING dstnc <= 2 
ORDER BY prop.sleeps ASC, prop.package ASC;
```

The first suggestion is an index on `availability(ucode)` or `availability(date, ucode)`.  There is a good chance that this will fix the performance problem.

Comment: Yes the unique_code in prop table is unique. Property tables contain between 400 - 4000 records of about 20-30 columns, while the availability table contain near 500,000 records

Answer (score 0):

You do the join by `prop.unique_code = avail.ucode`
but filter later by `avail.ucode IS NULL`, so this doenst make much sense.

So `prop.unique_code` have to be also `NULL`.

Comment: I was previously told to add the "avail.ucode IS NULL", but the purpose is to return property data where the unique_code value doesn't appear in the availability table for the dates provided